# Django Session Management

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

I am creating a Django based web application.
I want to learn how to manage session in that.
I browsed several tutorials but not got appropriate reference.
I have 3 urls in my urls.py with 3 seperate function to handle it.
`1. Login (login.html with login function) 
 2. Homepage (homepage.html with homepage function) 
 3. Logout (logout.html)`.

I able to create session on `Login page` successfully once credential has been verified but I am not able to `redirect it` perfectly on `Homepage and homepage function`. So `Logout button`, on homepage not able to work perfectly.

So in sort I want to know how to redirect pages with functional calls, not only HTML page. So homepage function also can work.

Comment: Sessions and redirects are two very different things.

Comment: I am able to create session on login page and now I want to redirect at homepage and i have logout button on homepage. Once I click it should destroy my session and redirect it to logout page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but I am not able to redirect it perfectly on Homepage and homepage
>   function

Your problem is not about sessions. Basically you need to,

- Redirect users to `home page` after successful `login` attempt
- Redirect users to `login page` after `logout` attempt

I would advise you to use built-in [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views):

> Django provides several views that you can use for handling login,
>   logout, and password management. These make use of the stock auth
>   forms but you can pass in your own forms as well.

With these built-in authentication views you can also set default redirection url after a successful login attempt in your `settings.py` file:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
```

You can find more details about `AUTH SETTINGS` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth)

If you don't want to use Django's auth system and use your own views, You can find more details and some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests).

And yes, `Django` has one of the most detailed and clean documentation web site on the internet. It is easy and fun to view!

Comment: Hi Thank you for response. Yes this works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for Django's `redirect` function. Here's a link to their documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect